# Rspec testing against local DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rspec

I am currently running a application that is moving data from an API into a MySQL database with Ruby 2.1.4 with MySQL2 gem.

I am trying to create RSPEC tests for this application but the problem is that the application is mainly MySQL queries and I do not want to mock out the query calls as I want to test my queries to make sure they are working as expected.

I have tried to do it by changing the client to sqlite3 gem when running rspec locally but the issue is that SQLite3 and MySQL2 don't handle queries the same. (Mysql2 uses Client.query where SQLite uses Client.execute).

I am attempting to emulate rails + rspec with how it uses sqlite locally but mysql remotely.

How could I go about doing this locally without having to spin up a external server? 
Do I need to use ActiveRecord or is there some way to create a CSV file that I can pass to the MySQL client I am creating at the beginning of the application?

I appreciate any help I can get or any suggestions you might have as to how I can adjust my approach to this issue. Code snipppits are below:

RSPEC Tests
[RSPEC test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttwcV.png)

Ruby Application
[Ruby Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX3nC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to fit a round peg in a square hole, why not just entirely use MySQL in your test environment? sqlite3 doesn't always accurately emulate MySQL so you're likely to get more reliable testing by just setting up and using MySQL on your local machine. You may find your tests may run faster as  well.

Personally, I always test against the same type of database I'm running in production just to avoid issues like the one you describe.

Comment: @Anythony E - 
So I thought about doing that but to setup a sqlite database seems much easier than setting up a mysql database (I assumed I could use them interchangeably from my experience in rails). Also the advantage of sqlite is that I could include the test.db file in the source code so anybody could run the rspec's without having to install any other prerequisites outside of the gems. Whereas if I do it with mysql any user who wants to run tests against the code will have to run a mysql server locally on their machine. 

Unless there is a way to setup mysql locally that I am missing?

Comment: Yes, but the benefits far outweigh the costs. It's easier to setup sqlite, but harder to integrate and manage as there are many differences between sqlite and MySQL, and you'll eventually hit errors in prod that you didn't expect because your test suite didn't pick them up. It shouldn't be terribly difficult to setup and run MySQL locally either. You shouldn't need to check in `test.db` to source control since your tests should always run from a blank state anyhow.

Comment: I went ahead and ran it the way you suggested - pretty easy overall not as difficult as I was expecting to be honest. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Glad it helped! It will save you time and effort in the long run. I've stopped using sqlite for testing entirely and have never missed it. :)

Comment: After talking with some co-workers they suggest an alternative path would be to use active record and setup your Database.yml the same way rails does so that way you can be more separated from the DB. 

Downside is you have to create models to reflect the databases properly like rails has.

I believe this is overkill for my simple application but it would have been another route I could have taken.